# How to connect to SQL Server database behind bastion host (Windows)

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, bastion-host

I have a SQL Server database which I am connecting to via bastion host. Bastion server is a Windows server in AWS. So I need to first RDC to Windows bastion host from there I again need to RDC to the database server.

I have whitelisted my IP to bastion security group. I need to connect Tableau desktop to SQL Server now.

What configuration I need to place to make this happen?

Thanks

Comment: Have you opened up the relevant ports in the DB security group? Where is the Tableau instance, in AWS as well?

Comment: its outside aws. We can attach static ip to the machine and whitelist it in bastion host.

Comment: DB server can accept request from bastion only.

Comment: Ok cool, a reverse proxy should do the trick. You can set it up on your bastion host and forward your Tableau traffic through to the backend DB server. Check this one for example: https://dev.to/jordonr/reverse-proxy-ms-sql-with-nginx-3e90